# How can I achieve displaying data points on chart but Dotted? Chart.js V3.7.0

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I was wondering is there an option that can make data points being displayed like this:
[image]

and if yes, what is the option's name for xAxis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `showLine` property to false in the root of the options for all datasets or on a per dataset level:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        showLine: false // Hide line for only this dataset
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    showLine: false // Hide the line for all datasets
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```